# How to display a specific date of a variable?

Tags: php, date, time

```
$dateCreated = date("$gU->datecreated d-m-y");
echo "$dateCreated";
```

I'm trying to make it so it displays the user's specific join date in a day-month-year form... How do I make it so it displays it like that?
($gU->datecreated) is their join date defined in regular time();

Comment: Probably something like: `date("d-m-y",$gU->datecreated);`

Answer (score 0):

as Rasclatt say you can use:

```
date("d-m-y",$gU->datecreated);
```

but $gU->datecreated should be a integer timestamp

You can read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php